# shell_exec, imagemagick convert doesn't seem to like dollars

Tags: php, imagemagick

This works:

`shell_exec('convert Q39.pdf Q39.png');`

Whereas this doesn't:

`$id = 39; 
shell_exec('convert Q$id.pdf Q$id.png');`

Within another shell_exec with another command (pdflatex) it works. Somehow the $id is ignored, so the file isn't found, so by doing:

`$id = 39; 
shell_exec('convert Q39.pdf Q$id.png');`

I get a correct file named Q.png.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use variables in string-literals you have to either use the double quotes:

```
$id = 39; shell_exec("convert Q$id.pdf Q$id.png");
```

or concatenate them:

```
$id = 39; shell_exec('convert Q'.$id.'.pdf Q'.$id.'.png');
```

I'd recommend the second way as it is more readable when using syntax highlighting.

Or even better, ensure it's always a decimal:

```
$id = 39; shell_exec(sprintf('convert Q%1$d.pdf Q%1$d.png', $id));
```

This will also show you which variables are used to build the command.